# How to resolve the "Minimal BASH-like line editing..." error after updating?

Tags: updates, error

I updated ElemOS (latest version) on my elderly mother's laptop. I opened the terminal and "sudo apt update" and "sudo apt upgrade" as opposed to doing it via the AppCenter.

I left while the updates were busy downloading. My mother said she closed the laptop after it was done. (I can't confirm whether it WAS actually done or not -as mentioned above, I left while it was busy.)
The next day when the laptop was booted, the following message appeared:

[image: Minimal BASH-like error]

When I eventually got my hands on the laptop, the following happens after booting up:

[image: Secure Boot forbids error]

I put the NVME drive into an external enclosure, with the hopes of accessing the data from the home folder in order to copy the most important docs...and then do a fresh install after, but it doesn't allow me access. I can see the drive in Gparted and Gnome Disks but I can't get into it via a file browser to copy the data. I did not encrypt the drive when I did the initial install.

When I boot into a live session and look at the drive in Gparted there are 2 partitions:

[image: Gparted]

I don't ever recall seeing the 2nd partition (which is root and data) named "lvm2pv data" before now. Also, at least a quarter of the drive was free before the update started. Now it shows as full..?

When I choose "Custom Install (Advanced)" from the USB, I see:

[image: Custom Install]

When I first installed ElemOS I just chose the stock standard "Erase Disk and Install" since it was a brand new machine.

I tried to mount the external drive via the various "mount" commands, but nothing works.

I'm obviously not a power user and (again obviously) don't have the level of knowledge/skill to resolve this. All my searches take me to 6 year old "solutions" -which I tried, but failed.
I'm really not sure what else to do. Any suggestions would be most welcome.

TIA.